# Spotfire excel export with merged cells

Tags: excel, csv, merge, ironpython, spotfire

I am using iron python script to export Spotfire crosstable to excel ouput. 
Before exporting i am adding headings and then table content.  while adding a haading is there a way to merge cells and export

i am using the below string

Heading10= ',,,'  +  'All Funds'  +  ',,,'  + 'Benchmark' +  ',,,,Performance Attribution,,,Difference'
and current output is

[image]

But i am expecting output like below.
[image]

Is there a way to do it?

## Script i used is

```
from System.IO import *
from System import Environment, Threading 
import clr
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot, HtmlTextArea
import clr
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
vc=Visuals.As[VisualContent]()  #Visuals = Script parameter for 
Table/Cross Table visualization
memStream = MemoryStream();
sWriter = StreamWriter(memStream);
#Exporting the data to Memory Stream
vc.ExportText(sWriter);  #exports data in tab separated text
sReader = StreamReader(memStream);
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

#Column Header heading 4&5 are calculated column and will generate the value based on user selection. also i have if else condition for Heading 10
Heading10=',,,'+Heading4+',,,'+Heading5+',,,,Attribution,,,Difference'

Filenm = 'Export_csvOutput.csv';
newtemp ="\\\\share1\\folder1\\"

filename=newtemp+Filenm
print filename
f=open(filename,"w+")
counter=0
j=0
str1=''

f.write("Attribution Dashboard"+'\n')
f.write(Heading2+'\n') #Subheading1
f.write(Heading3+'\n') #Subheading2
f.write(Heading6+'\n') #subheading3
f.write("US Dollar"+'\n')#subheading5
f.write('\n'+'\n')
f.write(Heading10+'\n')
while (sReader.Peek()>=0):
line=[]
counter=counter+1 #counts the number of rows in dataset
a=sReader.ReadLine()
lines=a.split("\t")
for elem in lines:
    j=j+1 # counts the number of columns in dataset
    #print elem
    if str(elem).find(",")<>-1:
        elem='"'+elem+'"'  # escaping comma already present in string
    line.append(elem)
str1 = ','.join(str(e) for e in line)
f.write(str1+'\n')
f.close();
MemoryStream.Dispose(memStream);
sReader.Close()
```

Comment: it would be easier to diagnose your issue if you provide your code, please :)

Comment: Hi @niko, i added the script.